# SQL Window Function to get addresses with more than 1 unique last name present (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, window-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table which includes addresses, state, first names and last names.
I would like to get a query that shows me only the addresses where more than 1 individual with a different last name is present.

So for example, assume that I have

```
address     | fname | lname    |State
10 lake road| John  | Smith    |FL
10 lake road| Julie | Gallagher|FL
3 gator cove| Jack  | Hoyt     |FL
3 gator cove| Debra | Hoyt     |FL
```

I would like the query to return only 1 row in that example: 10 lake road. Because it's the only house where there is more than 1 unique last name present.

I am currently using

```
SELECT  distinct a.address, a.fname, a.lname, a.state
FROM clients_addresses a
WHERE a.state = 'FL'
qualify count(1) over( partition by a.lname) > 1 
order by a.address
```

However, this is just returning the addresses where there is more than 1 person, it doesn't care if the last name is repeated. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

I can't quite understand where the query is going wrong. Snowflake doesn't like using any distinct keyword after the initial select, and even if I use it, it only returns 1 occurrence of each address, but it's still just addresses with more than 1 person, even if there was only 1 last name in the address.

It doesn't need to involve the keyword "qualify", I know Snowflake also accepts other things such as subselects that might help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the query to return only 1 row in that example: 10 lake road.

This sounds like aggregation:

```
SELECT a.address, count(*)
FROM clients_addresses a
WHERE a.state = 'FL'
GROUP BY a.address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.lname) > 1;
```

If you want the original rows (which is not what your question asks for), you can use:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM clients_addresses a
WHERE a.state = 'FL'
QUALITY COUNT(DISTINCT a.lname) OVER (PARTITION BY a.address) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Would removing the group by clause break the logic? What I meant when I said I only wanted 10 lake road was that I only wanted that whole row, not interested in seeing it pop twice because I already know its a house with more than 2 people in it, so using group by doesn't let me select more than 1 more column.

Also, I know that Oracle has this function where it adds a new column with the amount of the count, is this possible in snowflake too? It would be useful to see the amount of different individuals per address.

Thank you for the 2nd query, it was indeed useful to verify,

Comment: @Elmambo2194 . . . That doesn't make sense.  Presumably you want the value of the address (which the first query gives you) or you want *all* rows with that address.  It doesn't really make sense to arbitrarily choose one matching row, in my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself well enough.
I have no need to see 10 lake road popping there twice, because I'm counting the households with more than 1 person in them. But its useful for example, to get a new column called "Amount of people with different last name" where the value would be, the value of that count. so it would give me 1 row: 10 lake road, 2 people in this house

Comment: @Elmambo2194 . . . Just use `count(*)` then.